# Test if isContains with multiple world possibility

Tags: timezone, boolean, contains

I want to set up timeZone boolean like if mobile timeZone is America/New_Yor boolean is true.
it have to check multiple .contains America/New_York OR America/Chicago OR America/Denver OR America/Los_Angeles OR America/Anchorage OR America/Adak

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
boolean isContains = tz.getID().contains();
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `TimeZone`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZoneId` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: To attract users who know about your programming language and your brand of mobile it’s a good idea to tag your question with those.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your time work.

```
    List<ZoneId> relevantUsTimeZones = Arrays.asList(
            ZoneId.of("America/New_York"),
            ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"),
            ZoneId.of("America/Denver"),
            ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"),
            ZoneId.of("America/Anchorage"),
            ZoneId.of("America/Adak"));

     boolean isContains = relevantUsTimeZones.contains(ZoneId.systemDefault());
     System.out.println(isContains);
```

Output when I ran in Europe/Copenhagen time zone:

> false

And in America/Anchorage time zone:

> true

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.